# How do I find global rotation values of a child object?

Tags: modeling

Object1 is a child of Object2. I rotated Object2 thus rotating Object1. In the Transform section of the N panel Rotation values of Object1 are 0,0,0. How do I get global values of rotation of Object1 related to world?

This may seem trivial when you have only 2 objects, but actually I have a chain of child-parent relations, each one rotated by some degree. Calculating this by hand would take ages.

I need to align rotation of the object that is not part of this child-parent chain with the object that is.

[image: child rotation]

Comment: Could you add an image that describes the situation with parented objects and the independent one you want to align? The transformation of a child to parent is stored in the child object's matrix_parent_inverse see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/parenting-messes-up-transforms-where-is-the-offset-stored/3765#3765

Comment: I added the image, I'd prefer to avoid Python scripting if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add a **Copy Rotation** constraint to the object you want to rotate. In constraint panel, set Target to that child object;
2. After seeing it being aligned well, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> >  **Visual Transform**;
3. Delete that constraint, since you don't need it anymore.

---

Edit:

If you just want to "know" the global rotation info, you can simply <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > **Clear and Keep Transformation**, then you will see the visual rotation applied, which is the global rotation. After getting what you want, you can simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to undo.

Comment: After your suggestion, I (finally) updated the gif in [my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26114/2217).

Comment: @David LOL cool! things now become more convincable. :D

Comment: "Clear and Keep Transformation" seems the simplest solution to me, I actually stumbled upon it today and came here to update my answer and found your edit, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a dirty workaround, maybe someone will find a cleaner solution:

Select rotated child object that you would like to align to.
Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to align view to the object.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to align camera to view.

Now your camera's Transform Rotation data are equal to global rotation of your child object.

- Select object you would like to align.
- Shift select your camera.
- Go to object tab.
- Hover your mouse over rotation values, press right mouse button, select "Copy to selected".

Voila, your object has the desired global rotation values.

Answer (score 0):

Object A - object you want to know transform and rotation of.

Object B - object in world origin with zero transform and rotate

1. Parent B to A (keep transform)
2. Look the properties of B
3. Undo parenting

This works with objects in parenting or constrain links